Is it possible to attach some Action on tap on selected range of AttributedString?
There is a possibility to open link by tapping some part of AttributedString like this:
var string = AttributedString(text)
string[range].link = url
string[range].foregroundColor = .blue
string[range].underlineStyle = .single

I wanted to ask if there is some way to attach any other action to a specific range of AttributedString to open e.g. some specific screen of the application.

See Mixorok's answer in the duplicate target. You can use onOpenUrl to intercept the "opening a URL" event and do whatever else you want instead.
